# Exoplayer not playing video only audio plays

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, exoplayer

`ExoPlayer` is not showing the video. I can listen the audio but video is not playing. I am using the `Exoplayer` in the `Recyclerview`.I only can see the black screen and listen to audio.I am not able to track the problem. I am playing the `HLS` video in the `ExoPlayer`.

Comment: Which version you used for ExoPlayer?

Comment: @Palak  compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r1.5.9'

Comment: You test on which android version?

Comment: @Palak Tested on API 19..

Comment: @Palak its working if working  normally using Activity only, in adapter its not working.

Comment: @Sikha Oh I see, then you need to check context or compare both code

Comment: @Palak i took reference from there only.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120307/discussion-between-palak-and-shikha-ratra).

Comment: I had the same problem, is your problem solved now? Please share your solution

Comment: @PrasannaSundar yes!! my problem is solved...i have added my edited code above...

Comment: Can you just tell me what was the change you made? There is a bunch of code that is changed above... I have been facing this problem for a week

Comment: you can also add it as an answer below. Pls!

Comment: @PrasannaSundar i have change the whole code.. that code was not creating the surface to display video...u can use this code if it helpful to you.

Comment: @ShikhaRatra Thanks! Even I have the same surface changing issue, but I am using TIF where surface will be given to me with interface. Is the surface null for you? was it the problem?

Comment: @PrasannaSundar yes..the surface was not creating in that code that's y only audio is playing..i have added the comment in the code from where you can start changing the code...are you using the exoplayer in the recyclerview

Comment: Nope, its complicated, its the view of another activity where only surface will be given to me. I am using Tv Input Framework. But I am using exoplayer for drawing over surface

Comment: @PrasannaSundar oh!! ok get the reference from the exoplayer latest lib. i used that to solve my problem..gud luck..

Comment: @ShikhaRatra Please share the code , I am also facing the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting same issue few days back, now posting it here so that it can make someone's life easy since this problem appears very often when we use Exoplayer with RecyclerView.

**Cause of the issue (in my case):**

PlayerView was getting changed every time I came on the screen (due to the presence of RecyclerView)

I handled it by setting the **player** each time on the PlayerView **object** inside showLivePlayer() method which is called each time recycler view enabled screen opens to play the video.

```
    public void showLivePlayer(PlayerView playerView, String videoURL, String tokenURL, ProgressBar progressBar){

        mPlayerView = playerView;
        if(player != null)
            mPlayerView.setPlayer(player);  //THIS IS THE FIX

        mProgressBar = progressBar;
        //register event bus
        if (!EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this))
            EventBus.getDefault().register(this);

        shouldAutoPlay = true;
        bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        mediaDataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(mContext,
                Util.getUserAgent(mContext, mContext.getString(R.string.app_name)), bandwidthMeter);
        window = new Timeline.Window();
        getLiveVideoToken(tokenURL, videoURL);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

my bad was I was using PlayerControlView instead of PlayerView